# How do i skip blank spaces when printing from a stack

Tags: java, sorting, stack, tostring

When i print elements from my stack it will have a large amount of blank spaces or whitespace between each element.

I want to be able to print them out much closer together if possible.

It will retain the elements in the stack in their position and just negate all letters besides the one i am currently grabbing.

```
import java.io.*;

public class File 
{   
     public static void main(String[] args) {   
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new 
                                           FileReader("input.txt"));
            String str;
            while( (str = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("I just read: "+ str); 
                StackOfStrings[] ss = new StackOfStrings[35];
                for(int i=0; i <= 9; i++){
                    ss[i] = new StackOfStrings();    
                }
                if(str.charAt(4) == 'm') { 
                    ss[0].push("m");            
                }           
            }
            in.close(); 
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the other half without the interface

```
public class StackOfStrings implements StackInterface {

    private Node first; //top
    private int n;

    public StackOfStrings(){
        first = null;
        n=0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

    public void push(String item)
    {
        Node x = new Node();
        x.item = item;
        x.next = first;
        first = x;
    }

    public String pop() {
        String val = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        n--;
        return val;
    }

    private class Node {
        String item;
        Node next;
    }

public String toString()
{
    String s="";
    Node t = first;
    while(t != null) {
        s += t.item + " ";
        t= t.next;
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a new method with the following signature:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Create some string based on your class
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to @override

Comment: @notyou indeed you are correct

Comment: thank you for your help , i have the toString method now